# People Search returns wrong link to user profile

Tags: 2013, search, user-profile

I have a problem with people search, when I search for a person peoples results are shown but when I click people name I am redirected back to search center url. When I hover my mouse over user's name link points to search center url instead of user's personal site. I checked user profile and search settings few times and I have ran out of any clues..

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking the Content Source and the line that begins with SPS3:// that should be a valid Web Application in the default Zone. Next check your Alternate Access Mapping for the My Site Host. Often this is the problem. If it is none of these please comment and provide the URLs for all of the above. (Or at least examples.)